# How to run python from Flutter (Android)

Tags: python, android, flutter, dart

I want to call a python function that uses numpy and pandas from my flutter app and get the output of this function.

I found a way to do that by using ffi package but I don't know how.
some says that I can do this by making a .dylib file from the python project then use this code to call it

```
final path = absolute('native/libadd.dylib');
              final dylib = DynamicLibrary.open(path);
              final add = dylib.lookupFunction('add');
```

but I am getting this error

```
: Error: Expected type 'NativeFunction<Function>' to be a valid and instantiated subtype of 'NativeType'.
lib/home_screen.dart:32
 - 'NativeFunction' is from 'dart:ffi'.
 - 'Function' is from 'dart:core'.
              final add = dylib.lookupFunction('add');
```

so I think it's not available on Android

Comment: Please remove the C tag.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using [Flet](https://flet.dev/) for this. It is totally writted in Python language and still provide complete flutter functionality and code. Basic app code from it looks something like:

```
import flet as ft

def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.title = "Flet counter example"
    page.vertical_alignment = ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER

    txt_number = ft.TextField(value="0", text_align=ft.TextAlign.RIGHT, width=100)

    def minus_click(e):
        txt_number.value = str(int(txt_number.value) - 1)
        page.update()

    def plus_click(e):
        txt_number.value = str(int(txt_number.value) + 1)
        page.update()

    page.add(
        ft.Row(
            [
                ft.IconButton(ft.icons.REMOVE, on_click=minus_click),
                txt_number,
                ft.IconButton(ft.icons.ADD, on_click=plus_click),
            ],
            alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
        )
    )

ft.app(target=main)
```

It's just like a numpy or pandas library that you can import right into your project

Comment: it's great but how to compile this code into apk file to run on android

Comment: Yeah so about that... Flet does not support mobile platforms yet, you'll need to deploy a webapp through this though you can then use WebView to convert it to an apk